# Woocommerce Product Category taxonomy in Admin Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm writing a plugin for WordPress using WooCommerce. I need to get the list of WooCommerce Product Categories (taxonomy `'product_cat'`) **in the admin page** of the plugin (note the emphasis on "admin page").
However following calls to `get_categories()` and to `get_terms()` **filtering by taxonomy** result in error (I've simplified the code. Submenu class is somewhere else and as I understand it doesn't interfere):

```
add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_admin_settings' );
function myplugin_admin_settings() {
    $plugin = new Submenu( new MyPlugin_Admin_Page('myplugin_options') );
    $plugin->init();
}
class MyPlugin_Admin_Page {
    public function __construct($option_name) {
        $args = array(
            'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
            'hide_empty'   => false
        );
        var_export(get_categories( $args ));  // Prints 'error'
        var_export(get_terms( $args ));       // Prints 'error'
        var_export(get_terms());              // Prints the whole list of terms including those belonging to 'product_cat' taxonomy
    }
}
```

The error printed is:

```
WP_Error::__set_state(array(   'errors' =>   array (    'invalid_taxonomy' =>     array (      0 => 'Invalid taxonomy.',    ),  ),   'error_data' =>   array (  ),))array (  '' => NULL,)
```

Which indicates that taxonomy doesn't exist. And indeed if I call to `taxonomy_exists('product_cat')` it says `false`. However the whole list of terms printed include those belonging to `'product_cat'`, which seems impossible if the taxonomy doesn't exist. That kills me. As an example:

```
  43 =>
  WP_Term::__set_state(array(
 'term_id' => 56,
 'name' => 'Accesorios',
 'slug' => 'accesorios',
 'term_group' => 0,
 'term_taxonomy_id' => 56,
 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
 'description' => '',
 'parent' => 0,
 'count' => 1,
 'filter' => 'raw',
  )),
```

These calls are done in `init` hook, so they should return the Product Categories.

Anyone can understand what's happening? Is there other way to get the Product Categories in Admin Pages?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I've tried also with hooks `plugins_loaded` and `woocommerce_init`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I don't know what really happened, but now it's working using `init` hook.
I tried before, but it didn't, not sure why. Now I just did 2 tests: use function `current_filter()` to check that the function itself was properly hooked; and hook to `init` a function containing the call to `get_terms($args)`. Then I noticed it was working and I undo the changes and everything was working. Ghost fail.

Comment: I don't get why the -1 to the answer. It still can give some helo to people, instead I could just delete it or delete the whole question, I don't care, but I think it can give hints to people to recheck parts of the code. And why the comment of somebody else who suggested using hook `woocommerce_init` is not here anymore.